# Getting selected value from dropdown menu to remain when page refreshes

Tags: html, django, forms

I am trying to figure out a way in Django to maintain the selected value in a dropdown menu, after the page refreshes. Here is the current code I have. Whenever I make a selection the page refreshes, showing the correct data associated with the selection, but defaults to the name of the top selection in the dropdown menu. Thanks for the help.

```
     <html>
       <form method="GET" action=".">


            <select name="option-menu" id="option-menu">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose a Name</option>
                {% for d in database %}
                    <option value="{{d.name}}">{{d.name}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        <button type="submit" class="btn-filter">Filter</button>
    </form>
    </html>

 --views.py--

option_menu = request.GET.get("option-menu")

qs = Database.objects.filter(database_id=id)

if option_menu != '' and option_menu is not None:
    qs = qs.filter(name__icontains=option_menu)

return render(request,
              template_name='main/database.html',
              context={"queryset": qs

                       })
```

Comment: In your view, do you save/update something (e.g a model instance) with the selected value? You can always pass back that selected value to the html from wherever you saved it

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function in your template that activates periodically, or on the click of a specific element that sends the selection to the view which saves it to a cache file.

Function to check the selection:

```
<script>
        function saveSelection() {
            var selection
            selection = $('#option-menu').val()
            dict = {}

            dict[selection] = selection
            
            $.ajax({
                    url: '//' + '' + '/' + '' + "/",
                    type: 'POST',
                    headers: {'X-CSRFtoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
                    data: dict,
                    dataType: 'json'
                })
            
        }
    </script>
```

You'll need to populate your own url in here, I couldn't glean it from your code above

In your view, you have a if statement to handle POST requests to save the selection, and you pass the selection into your context with a try block

```
try:
    savedInfo = {}
    csv_reader=csv.DictReader(saveFile)
    for row in csv_reader:
        if row['Selection'] == "Your selection text index 0":
            selection = 0
        elif row['Selection'] == "Your selection text index 1":
            selection = 1
        savedInfor[row['Selection']] == row['Selection']

    context['saveInfo'] = savedInfo
except:
    pass

if request.method == "POST":
    data = request.POST
    
    #save data
```

Then, on page load, you need a function to change the selection from the default value to the saved one

```
{% for info, value in saveInfo.items %}
        <script>

            $('document').ready(function(){
                $('#option-menu').prop('selectedIndex', '{{value.1}}'
        </script>
```

This probably isn't a perfect method for this, but it may push you in the right direction